# Equivalent of excel VBA array and loop in Openpyxl

Tags: excel, vba, openpyxl

I have been working with excel VBA.  I have created a script for comparing the current week's data with the previous week's data and take some actions based on that comparison.  This is the code used by me which runs really very efficiently.

```
arrc = currWs.Range("A1").CurrentRegion 'outer loop array from currWs
arrp = prevWs.Range("A1").CurrentRegion 'inner loop array from prveWs

For y = 1 To UBound(arrc, 1)
    For z = 1 To UBound(arrp, 1)
        If arrc(y, 5) = arrp(z, 5) Then
            currWs.Range("I" & y).Value = "matched"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next z
Next y
```

I want to replicate the same in python / openpyxl.

(1) Is there a way we can assign a range of values to a python list as given in the vba program?  can it be done in a single statement without a loop?

(2) I would also need in python the equivalent of the outer/inner loops given above

As I have to deal with two sets of 300000 rows, the code needs to be efficient.

Comment: You should include the Python code you've tried.

Comment: it looks like your script, does not match any particular data, only checks if  the value is different in the same location of data table. In this case,
you can load both data sets into 2 different dataframes and simply subtract Column x1 from data frame 1 and Column x2 from dataframe2. 
The cells with values not equal to 0, will be the ones you are looking for.
No looping

Comment: Hi Charlie, I am trying to assign values to the list (array) without a loop..  Could not find any solution on the net. Also, not sure how to replicate those array loops in python.   Hence raised this query in this forum.

Comment: Thanks NoobVB.  I am actually looking for a match.  Also, I am trying to do this looping through two lists (as in the vba example).

Comment: Oops, miss-read your code, - anyway, using my option, Nill value will give you match